# API document for props.client.subscribe from withApollo HOC

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

Where can I find the para document for props.client.subscribe

if I use withApollo HOC?

```
import React, {Component, PureComponent}          from 'react';
import PropTypes                                  from 'prop-types';
import {Subscription, Query}   from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';




export default function newHeartbeatHOC(ChildComponent) {
  class OuterComponent extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: {}
      }
    }

    subscribe = (gqlStr) => {
      this.props.client.subscribe({
        // how? 
      })

    }

    render() {
      return (<ChildComponent data={this.state.data} />)
    }
  }
  return withApollo(OuterComponent)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it in the apollo docs but the client.subscribe is expecting 1-3 arguments. query, variables (if any) and fetchpolicy (if any).

```
this.props.client.subscribe({
  query: YOUR_QUERY,
  variables: {{ id: 1 }},
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
})
```

Comment: subscribe function does not return a Promise. How can I get the return result?

Comment: what does it return if you log it?